# Can't get data from database with linq expression

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I want to get all usernames from my database so that when a new user wants to register i can check if the username already exists in the database. Im trying to do this with this linq expression:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Register()
{
    var q = from t in _db.User
            select t;
    return View();
}
```

But when i debugg it q becomes "Children could not be evaluated".
I don't know why i get this error so i just post some stuff that i think can have to do with it.

This is how i define _db above the Register method:

```
FantasySport _db = new FantasySport();
```

and here is the fantasysport database model:

```
public class FantasySport : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<UserProfile> User { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Team> Team { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TeamPlayer> TeamPlayer { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Player> Player { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Games> Games { get; set; }
    public DbSet<League> League { get; set; }
}
```

And here is UserProfile model:

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public int Birthdate { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Team> teams { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of the exception you are getting (and the exact exception message and the exception type)?

Comment: I added a picture to my question with the data you asked for :)

Comment: This is intended behavior: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1995. The reasons behind it are related to threading and preventing side effects by debugging.

Answer (score 0):

It's apparently [some complicated internal issue](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1898) with EF 6 when expanding EF query results in the Visual Studio debugger. But it will work if you just enumerate the results (`foreach (var item in q) { /* watch item in debugger */ }`) or call any execution operator like `var result = q.ToList();` in your code.

Comment: var q = from t in _db.User
                     select t;
            foreach (var item in q) {
                var a = item;
            }

This gives me "The loop doesn't have any results" (Translated from swedish)

Comment: @DanielGustafsson: Where does this message appear? At which line? Is it an exception?

Comment: that message appers in the same way as my original question, when i debugg and hoover above the q in the foreach loop

Comment: @DanielGustafsson: If you set a breakpoint at your line `var a = item;` doesn't your code stop at that line? If it does `a` is the user in your database and you should be able to inspect `a` in the debugger.

Comment: @DanielGustafsson: Normally it can only mean that the table is empty. Perhaps your connection string doesn't point to the correct database? Does `var result = q.ToList()` contain any entries or is it an empty list?

Comment: This is my connectionstring:
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=SportsFantasy;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\SportsFantasy.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

I don't know what to even search for anymore. Just can't find the problem :(